# Is it OK to ask what type of interview will be conducted?

Tags: recruitment

Is it OK to ask the recruiter what kind of interview will be conducted - i.e Panel, or one-on-one?

How can I phrase this question in a polite way?

Comment: Why does it matter to you?

Comment: @MaskedMan : uneducated guess : to prepare psychologically.

Comment: Asking the question and being prepared is way better than just walking in there without even knowing! Especially through the company's eyes

Comment: I always ask this sort of thing. Whether I'll meet my team, if there is a test, how long it's expected to take etc

Answer (score 10):

It's absolutely OK to ask this question, same as asking whether it's a technical interview or you're talking to HR. I don't think anyone will hold it against you.

I've always asked something along the lines of, "Could you tell me who I will be talking to?" which kills two birds with one stone as not only tells you how many people will take part in the interview but also gives you information about your interview partners (i.e. their position in the company).

Answer (score 7):

'Do you know if the interview will be a panel or one on one?'